# Why there are these two unnormal information?

Tags: jhipster

When I use jhipster to create Monolithic application, there are two fail log information as below when type mvnw to compile:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js
[INFO] Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[INFO] Failed to parse source map from 'D:\appt\node_modules\@reduxjs\toolkit\dist\module.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\app\node_modules\@reduxjs\toolkit\dist\module.js.map'
[INFO]
[INFO] WARNING in DefinePlugin
[INFO] Conflicting values for 'process.env.NODE_ENV'
[INFO]
[INFO] 1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
[INFO] webpack 5.39.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 27825 ms
```

One information above is failed to parse..... and another is conflicting values for .........
I want to know hor to fix these two issues and why they happend?

Comment: First one is not about jhipster, it is about a third party dependency that cannot find one file, check with their project.

Comment: The first one is a known issue. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16116